# Oracle stored procedure every six months

Tags: oracle

I'm very new to the use of stored procedures. From the Oracle docs I could understand that, schedule intervals could only be Daily, Hourly, Monthly, or Yearly.

Is there any way we can schedule them every six months so that they run on a Sunday or Saturday?

Comment: Add some logic to your procedure to check it's the right time when it runs, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: I'm very naive at it currently. So just to make it to understand my self . Will the logic go where we write repeat_interval=> freq=monthly/yearly then a logic to have it one 1th and the 7th month of the year ??

Comment: Just have it run every day...if the current day is not 1/1 or 7/1 exit...make sure you have an optional override parameter in case something happens and you need to manually run it

Comment: Use cron. It's very simple and flexible enough to accommodate the craziest schedules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the stored procedure to do what it does without worrying about the schedule within the stored procedure.

Then use DBMS_SCHEDULER to control how often the stored procedure runs.

In your case somethings like:

```
begin
   dbms_scheduler.create_job (
     job_name        => 'the_job',
     job_type        => 'plsql_block',
     job_action      => 'begin the_store_proc; end;',
     start_date      => systimestamp,
     repeat_interval => 'freq=monthly; interval=6;',
     enabled         => true);
end;
/
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Just to conclude this thread. So if we want to schedule this every 6 months interval and first Sunday of that month. 
Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: We should be writing the something like this.
begin dbms_scheduler.create_job ( job_name => 'the_job', job_type => 'plsql_block', job_action => 'begin the_store_proc; end;', start_date => systimestamp, repeat_interval => 'freq=monthly; interval=6; byday=1sun', enabled => true); end; /